# Update status of a column w.r.t multiple conditional values of other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have 3 tables X,Y and Z

I want to update the status column of table X w.r.t certain
conditional checks of table Y and Z.

> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "udpate tableX..." - rest of line

ignored and also x.status as invalid identifier.

```
update tableX x 
set x.status='M'
where not exists
  (select 1 
   from tableY y
         , tableZ z 
   where z.clcode    = x.clcode
   and   z.desg      = '2'
   and z.mgtco     = NVL(x.company,z.mgtco)
   and   y.company = z.mgtco
   and   y.id      = z.fndno
   and   y.flag = 'Y'
   and   trim(x.status) is null);
```

Comment: udpate  <> update; you have a typo. Also, closing bracket (for subquery) is missing).

Comment: You should edit the question again, posting which error(s) you have now. If it is still "x.status is invalid identifier", it means that there's no column whose name is "status" in table "x".

Comment: I don't know what you "fixed", because error - again - says that **uDPate** is an unknown command. Have a coffee, then come back and post something we can work with.

Comment: yeah you are right ,Its actually working post changing those update and parentheses...